# Solution from VS2015 CTP3 broken in VS2014 CTP4

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I have a solution that I creating in VS14 ctp3 and it worked perfectly.
Updated to VS14 ctp4 and I have loads of errors.

```
Error   Diagnostic_CS   2   'CancellationToken' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Threading'.
```

How?

> Error Diagnostic_CS   4   Method 'Public Sub Check_FormatString(node As
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberAccessExpressionSyntax, sm
>   As Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SemanticModel, addDiagnostic As
>   System.Action(Of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic), ct As
>   CancellationToken, fsi As Integer, ArgObjs As
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object))' does not have a
>   signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub System.Action(Of
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberAccessExpressionSyntax,
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SemanticModel, System.Action(Of
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic), CancellationToken, Integer,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object))(arg1 As
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberAccessExpressionSyntax,
>   arg2 As Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SemanticModel, arg3 As System.Action(Of
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic), arg4 As CancellationToken, arg5 As
>   Integer, arg6 As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object))'.]

I don't even understand the delegate that is referred to in the second. What's with the arg1, arg2 parameters.

> Error Diagnostic_CS   71  Class 'DiagnosticAnalyzer' must implement 'Sub AnalyzeNode(node As Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode, semanticModel As Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SemanticModel, addDiagnostic As System.Action(Of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic), options As Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerOptions, cancellationToken As System.Threading.CancellationToken)' for interface 'ISyntaxNodeAnalyzer(Of SyntaxKind)'.

It's implemented. I think it is happen because cancellationToken is reported as ambiguous.

What it the underlying cause / issue so I can fix it?

**Edit**

The loading the solution, the projects have references missing to

```
System.Runtime
System.Threading
```

Tried adding the reference missing references. Still can't compile.

Comment: What kind of solution? A diagnostic? Perhaps you need to change the assemblies it references to a newer version?

Comment: @JoshVarty I'm certain if the reference issues were fixed it would compile.

Comment: You are an unpaid beta tester when you tinker with CTP editions.  The proper way to report bugs is to post them to connect.microsoft.com,  not here.

Comment: Try creating a new project from scratch and add the source files and references you had in the previous project to it. Save and compare the resulting project files. That's what I do whenever I switch VS versions and the projects files act strangely.

Comment: @HansPassant: yes, CTPs are unsupported, but we want to offer all the help we can to those who are spending their valuable time using our stuff. The Roslyn team monitors StackOverflow and considers this a perfectly acceptable place to ask questions such as this one.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you uninstalled the VSIX you might have installed from your previous installation? Maybe as part of testing, etc.?

Comment: @mjsabby I uninstalled the ctp3 version then installed the ctp4 version.

Comment: Also submitted to connect.microsoft.com (VS14)

Comment: Ok, I was asking if you had left your VSIX installed, such that VS 14 CTP4 was picking it up. In any case, %APPDATA%\..\Local\NuGet -- delete that folder or its contents. Also clean up %APPDATA%\..\LocaMicrosoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions

Let's see if that helps.